# When I use pycharm to run code, the error "OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address" happended.

Tags: python, console, pycharm

More details:
Macbook Air 10.12.6 (16G1036);
Python version: python3.6
IDE: Pycharm 2017.3.1

Error:
Users/lrh/PycharmProjects/TensorFlowDemo/venv/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 51562 51563 /Users/lrh/PycharmProjects/TensorFlowDemo/demo1.py
Error starting server with host: "localhost", port: "51562", client_port: "51563"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 270, in start_console_server
    server = XMLRPCServer((host, port), logRequests=False, allow_none=True)
  File "/Users/lrh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/server.py", line 598, in **init**
    socketserver.TCPServer.**init**(self, addr, requestHandler, bind_and_activate)
  File "/Users/lrh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in **init**
    self.server_bind()
  File "/Users/lrh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address
Console server didn't start

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because the console uses the port 51562 and 51563. So you might didnt exit a program correctly to cause the ports are still using.

Comment: thanks. It seems the problem is related with the version of IDE. I'v return to the Pycharm2017.2, and everything is ok. Thanks again.